# How to check publishing or rendering context using TOM.NET in the new publishing framework

Tags: web8, publishing, templating, tom.net, preview

With regards to publishing and rendering in TOM.NET, I know the following is true for the legacy publishing framework (pre Web 8):

### Template Builder

`PublicationTarget` is `null`, `RenderMode` is `PreviewDynamic`

### CME Preview

`PublicationTarget` ID is `tcm:0-0-0` (or `TcmUri.UriNull`), `RenderMode` is `PreviewDynamic`

### Session Preview

`PublicationTarget` ID is the real Target ID, `RenderMode` is `PreviewDynamic`

### Publish

`PublicationTarget` ID is the real one, `RenderMode` is `Publish`

Then you can use the following example code to determine the current mode:

```
private CurrentMode GetCurrentMode()
{
    RenderMode renderMode = _engine.RenderMode;
    if (renderMode == RenderMode.Publish) 
    {
        return CurrentMode.Publish;
    }

    if (renderMode == RenderMode.PreviewDynamic)
    {
        if (_engine.PublishingContext.PublicationTarget == null) 
        {
            return CurrentMode.TemplateBuilder;
        }
        PublicationTarget target = _engine.PublishingContext.PublicationTarget;
        if (target.Id.Equals(TcmUri.UriNull)) 
        {
            return CurrentMode.CmePreview;
        }
        return CurrentMode.SessionPreview;
    }
    return CurrentMode.Unknown;
}

private enum CurrentMode
{
    TemplateBuilder,
    CmePreview,
    SessionPreview,
    Publish,
    Unknown
}
```

How does this change in the new publishing framework introduced in SDL Web 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all is well, the same logic can still be used; the new publishing franework uses Topology Manager Mappings instead of Publication Targets, but you will find that there is still a `PublicationTarget` set in the API (a so-called *emulated* Publication Target). This is done for backward compatibility purposes.

If you want to avoid using (now deprecated) Publication Targets in your code, you can use `Engine.PublishingContext.TargetType` instead.

BTW: I was not aware that there is a difference between Template Builder (TemplateDebugHost) and CME Preview w.r.t. `PublicationTarget`; not sure if that (unintentional) distinction also exists when using Topology Manager based publishing.

Comment: In case I wanted to use `Engine.PublishingContext.TargetType` instead, what would the "rules" then be to make a distinction between preview and publish in the different scenarios?

Comment: Basically the same. Preview and Debugging do not have a Target Type, Session Preview and Publish do. The latter two can be distinguished by Render Mode.  I think that Debugging can be detected by the type of `Engine`.