# Unable to read PublicationTarget in Razormediator Template Building block

Tags: web8.5, razormediator, template-building-blocks

I am trying to read PublicationTarget Title as explained in the following link
https://www.curlette.com/?p=1038

using below code snippet

```
    @{
var engine = TridionHelper.Engine;
var publishContext = engine.PublishingContext;
var pubTargetTitle = publishContext.PublicationTarget.Title;
}
```

But I am getting null exception as I am getting PublicationTarget null.
We are using SDL Web 8.5

Can you please help me to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Prasanna , Are you using Topology setup for publishing target or you using Legecy Publishing Target.

Comment: Hi Anand, Thank you for your quick response, Yes I am using Topology setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

publishContext.PublicationTarget.Title; is not working with razor , you can use Engine.PublishingContext.TargetType and see if you can get the target , if not create a .net Code and use it on your Component Template

refer to this [link](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17266/how-to-check-publishing-or-rendering-context-using-tom-net-in-the-new-publishing)  for mofre details.

Comment: Thank you Anand, It worked To read Title we need to use Engine.PublishingContext.TargetType.Title

Comment: Happy it worked .You used the razor template.

Comment: Yes using razor mediator template